# Do or play sport(s)

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct in BrE? Is the meaning the same?

1. "I never play sports."
2. "I never play sport."
3. "I never do sports."
4. "I never do sport."

Comment: In AmE 1 would be by far the most common, but I am not sure about BrE..

Comment: _Play_ is appropriate for sports which are games, such as tennis or football, but I'm not sure that it is for individual contests such as athletics.

Comment: Some people might say 'do' these days, but it is informal.

Comment: Thus each sentence is correct. Right? Sports in BrE is plural, not singular, isn't it?

Comment: I never do any sports. And I am AmE speaker.

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer, as I'm neither a Briton nor an authority on BrE, but I'm with Lambie on this one: I never **play** football or tennis, because I never **do** any sports at all. I think maybe my resistance to using "play" with "sports" as an object has to do with the fact that there are so many specific sports – like track, swimming, and skiiing – that one does not "play."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, we use '*play*' in connection with sports, but do be clear on what you mean by "sport". There is a difference between sports, which are usually 'games' characterised by competition between individuals or teams, and other forms of physical activity which can be carried out alone, perhaps for the purpose of exercise, but can also be competitive.

For example, we 'play' football, badminton, golf etc. We would not use that verb in connection with running or swimming, for example.

A person might say "I do swimming" (or other activities), especially if they do it 'seriously' or even professionally, but it would not be quite as idiomatic as "I am a swimmer". A less serious swimmer may say "I *go* swimming", or "I swim".

Your examples sound best with '*play*', although if you switched the word 'sports' for 'exercise', the verb would be '*do*'.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. "I am a swimmer" is said by someone who does it seriously. Do I understand correctly?